# Set CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT by command line

Tags: curl

I am trying to make curl NOT get a cached response. I read that with PHP you can use `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` but how would I set this via the command line say for a cron job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But there's rarely any need to. The command line tool can't re-use any existing connections when you invoke it, so it has to start fresh.

Of course, if you specify multiple URLs on the command line all but the first one may be subject for re-use.

Connection re-use is not really the same as "not getting a cached response" though.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there any way curl would use a cached result? If it is getting a cached response would the only cause be from the server not curl itself? I have a cron job setup calling curl for a simple get request but the cron deamon always emails me the same response when I know it would be different. Thanks

Comment: Based on log output from `curl -v`, it _does_ reuse connections when retrying a request with `--retry`. So... is there any way to set `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` when using commandline `curl`?